# What is the difference between Mac OS X pre-installed Python and the one from Python.org?

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard

I am a new Mac (Snow Leopard) user and I found that Python is pre-installed in Mac OS X. What is the difference between Mac OS X pre-installed Python and the one from Python.org?

If I install the one from Python.org, will it break anything? Will it be redundant?

**EDIT**
What would be a good reason to prefer the Python.org version, comparing identical version numbers head-to-head?

Comment: Might want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541776/upgrade-python-to-2-6-on-mac) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723183/is-it-safe-to-replace-macos-x-default-python-interpreter). They both have some good information on this. The typical solution is usually to just install a newer version alongside the system one, but that can depend somewhat on your reason for wanting to do this.

Comment: @elderathis: Yes, that is actually what I'm trying to get at--reasons for preferring Python.org over the Mac pre-installed version. Let me edit my question.

Comment: "identical version numbers".  They're the same version.  They do the same things.  They're built from the same source.  What are you asking?

Comment: They're not the same minor version.  See below.

Answer (score 3):

The Apple-supplied Python 2.6 in Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) is currently 2.6.1 (and, based on previous OS X releases, it is unlikely Apple will update it to a newer version in a 10.6.x maintenance release).  The most recent (and likely final) release of Python 2.6 is 2.6.6.  So if you install the most recent python.org release, you will get the benefit of a large number of bug fixes that have been made over the lifetime of Python 2.6.  There are some other differences.  The python.org 2.6.x versions are built as 32-bit-only.  The Apple-suppled version is built as a 32-bit/64-bit universal and will, by default, prefer to run in 64-bit mode when possible.  Either one can lead to some issues when installing third-party packages with C extension modules that depend on other 3rd-party libraries.  There needs to be at least one common architecture (be it 32-bit, `i386`, or 64-bit, `x86_64`) among all the components.  Another difference is that the Apple-suppled 2.6 is linked with a new version of Tk 8.5; there are reported problems with the `IDLE` that comes with 10.6 and possibly with other applications using `Tkinter`.  If you plan to use either, you may be better off with the python.org 2.6 which is linked with Tk 8.4.

On OS X, it is particularly easy and common to install multiple Python versions even of the same major version.  If you do install the python.org version, by default the installer will modify your shell search `PATH` so that the python.org version is found first.  It will also be available via the absolute path `/usr/local/bin/python2.6`.  The Apple-suppled version will remain available as `/usr/bin/python2.6`.

FYI: Be aware that Python 2.7 has already been released and there are OS X installers for it available from python.org.  A new, not upwards-compatible version of Python, Python 3, is also available (currently 3.1.2 with 3.2 coming in a few months) and is expected to gradually replace Python 2 in popularity as new features are only being added to Python 3.

Comment: Python.org hosts an x86-64 `dmg` for the Mac OS X.

Comment: ... but only for Python 2.7 and for the upcoming 3.2 release, not 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell without knowing which version(s) you're comparing. You're best off doing `python --version` on your default OS X install, and then checking release notes from that version to subsequent versions. My guess (I don't have OS X) is that you're likely running 2.4.x or 2.5.x. There'll be very few regressive differences from 2.4.x forward on the 2.x version tree. Python 3.x introduces syntax changes, which will break some existing code. Perhaps the most visible change is `print` becomes a function in 3.0, while still a statement in 2.x.

In general, amongst 2.x, syntax is only enhanced, not broken. The changes are going to be more in the libraries (i.e. the md5 module is deprecated at 2.6 in favor of the hashlib module).

Comment: OS X 10.6 comes with Python 2.6 (and 2.5).